# Scattering a mesh grid over a grayscale image

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, mesh

I'm trying to create a numpy mesh grid according to a grayscale image. For example, considering this image

[image: Geometry figure]

I want to scatter points to get something similar to

[image: Scattered points]

in cartesian coordinates.
Is there any library for doing such a task or I need to implement something from scratch? Thanks in advance, I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Why has the white background suddenly gone transparent? Why are there 2 white points remaining on the left side? Why do you call this *"scattering"* - that normally means spreading things out, but you don't start with a bunch of round points so how do you end up with that? How about getting a list of all the black points, choosing a few hundred of them at random, then drawing black circles on an empty canvas at those positions?

Comment: Are you looking for points with a specific density (distance between points) or are you looking for a specific number of points spread out over that area? Are you looking for a uniform distribution of coordinates within the area, or are you looking for more even distances between points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing somewhat as to what you mean, here is an approach:

- load image as greyscale
- threshold to pure black and white
- get coordinates of all black pixels
- randomly subsample 0.5% of the coordinates
- create empty output image
- draw white circles on output image's alpha channel at the subsampled locations which will make the black background become visible at those locations

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# Load image as greyscale
im = cv.imread('Gkzaa.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Otsu threshold to pure black and pure white, i.e. 0 or 255
_, thresh = cv.threshold(im, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)

# Get X and Y coordinates of all black pixels
Y, X = np.where(thresh==0)
nBlack = len(Y)

# Get indices of 0.5% of those black pixels
indices = np.random.choice(nBlack, size=int(nBlack*0.005), replace=False)

# Form an empty (black) output image and an alpha channel for it
BGR = np.zeros((*im.shape,3), np.uint8)
A   = np.zeros_like(im)

# Draw circles of opacity into the alpha channel at selected indices
for i in indices:
    cv.circle(A, center=(X[i], Y[i]), radius=4, color=255, thickness=cv.FILLED)

# Stack the alpha channel onto the BGR channel to make BGRA and save
res = np.dstack((BGR,A))
cv.imwrite('result.png', res)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I was looking for. In fact, I want to use this grid as collocation points for solving a mathematical model. I really appreciate it.